# Can i change animation duration?

Tags: java, android, animation

i have method like this (in my custom imageview class):

```
public void startBlinking(int duration)
{
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setStartOffset(20);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    startAnimation(animation);
    blinking = true;
}
```

and in MainActivity I call this methdo like this:

```
my_status = (MyStatus) findViewById(R.id.my_status);
my_status.startBlinking(200); // duration = 200
my_status.startBlinkign(300);
```

and now, can i some way set just the duration? not start a new animation? Because the blinking is intermittent u know? Like this

->this is a imageview animation -> this is my imageview -> (imageview)

```
--- duration 200 ---
(imageview - visibility 100%)
(imageview - visibility 90%)
(imageview - visibility 80%)
-now I change the duration (animation...)
(imageview - visibility 100%)
(imageview - visibility 90%)
```

and that's the problem... I want smooth animation like this:

```
(imageview - visibility 100%)
(imageview - visibility 90%)
-- now i change the duration
(imageview - visibility 80%) - but slowly / faster
(imageview - visibility 70%)...
```

I hope you understand me :D, thank you for your answers!

Comment: Are you looking for an interpolator? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html

Comment: @fractalwrench probably nope, maybe I can try to create custom animation like runnable thread?

Comment: Yes, you would need a custom Animation.